# The most recognisable monument in / of Egypt

Tags: grammar, superlatives

It's common that we say: The Great Pyramid is the most recognisable monument in Egypt.
And we can also say: The Great Pyramid is Egypt's most recognisable monument.

Is the last one correct to be the same meaning as
The Great Pyramid is the most recognisable monument of Egypt.

At last, Is it correct to use in and of (of / in Egypt) alternatively. Namely if there's not 'in' , we can use 'of'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all three are idiomatic and yes, the last two have the same meaning.

Remember that King Tut's sarcophagus may be Egypt's most recognizable relic but it is not the most recognizable relic in Egypt if it is not currently **in** Egypt.

Comment: I am Egyptian, and the three Pyramids in Giza have been the most recognisable monument over the history. But the King Tut's sarcophagus is the most recognisable monument in Egypt since last century only

Comment: @MohammedSalim -  I was only speaking figuratively but I noticed my error in terminology and changed monument to relic.  A monument being fixed at its location and a relic being something that can be moved.  My point is that when the sarcophagus is touring England it is not **in** Egypt.